# EF Core failed to execute database update command : " fail: Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Database.Command[20102] "

Tags: c#, sql-server, .net-core, entity-framework-core, dbcontext

Guys I'm trying to run `dotnet ef database update` command but during the executing of it, it trows me an exception:

```
Failed executing DbCommand (12ms) [Parameters=[], CommandType='Text', CommandTimeout='30']
CREATE TABLE [ProductSubCategory] (
    [ProductId] int NOT NULL,
    [SubCategoryId] int NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT [PK_ProductSubCategory] PRIMARY KEY ([SubCategoryId], [ProductId]),
    CONSTRAINT [FK_ProductSubCategory_Product_ProductId] FOREIGN KEY ([ProductId]) REFERENCES [Product] ([ProductId]) ON DELETE CASCADE,
    CONSTRAINT [FK_ProductSubCategory_SubCategory_SubCategoryId] FOREIGN KEY ([SubCategoryId]) REFERENCES [SubCategory] ([SubCategoryId]) ON DELETE CASCADE
);
Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlException (0x80131904): Introducing FOREIGN KEY constraint 'FK_ProductSubCategory_SubCategory_SubCategoryId' on table 'ProductSubCategory' may cause cycles or multiple cascade paths. Specify ON DELETE NO ACTION or ON UPDATE NO ACTION, or modify other FOREIGN KEY constraints.
Could not create constraint or index. See previous errors.
Introducing FOREIGN KEY constraint 'FK_ProductSubCategory_SubCategory_SubCategoryId' on table 'ProductSubCategory' may cause cycles or multiple cascade paths. Specify ON DELETE NO ACTION or ON UPDATE NO ACTION, or modify other FOREIGN KEY constraints.
Could not create constraint or index. See previous errors.
```

I'm using **Sql Server** as my database provider and **Entity framework core 3.19** in my **ASP.NET CORE MVC** application. To be fair I'm not sure what is causing it, since i didn't have that troubles before, they appeared once I added foreign key properties such as `public int CategoryId { get; set; }`  on **all** dependent entities (on one to many relationships) such as Product because i forgot to add them before, and now i will use them in order to update the Product Entities.I'm showing the entities and fluent api code
**`Product.cs`**

```
public class Product
    {
        public int ProductId { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public double Price { get; set; }
        public Category Category { get; set; }
        public int CategoryId { get; set; } //It's one of the foreign keys properties added
        public Brand Brand { get; set; }
        public int BrandId { get; set; }    //It's one of the foreign keys properties added
        public string ImageName { get; set; }
        public IEnumerable<ProductSubCategory> SubCategories { get; set; }
}
```

**`ProductSubCategory.cs`**

```
public class ProductSubCategory
{
    public int ProductId { get; set; }
    public Product Product { get; set; }
    public int SubCategoryId { get; set; }
    public SubCategory SubCategory { get; set; }
}
```

**`SubCategory.cs`**

```
public class SubCategory
{
    public int SubCategoryId { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int CategoryId { get; set; }
    public Category Category { get; set; }
    [JsonIgnore]
    public IEnumerable<ProductSubCategory> ProductSubCategories { get; set; }
}
```

**`Category`**

```
public class Category
{
    public int CategoryId { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<Product> Products { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<SubCategory> SubCategories { get; set; }
}
```

**`DbContext.cs`**

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
        {
modelBuilder.Entity<ProductSubCategory>()
                .HasKey(psc => new {psc.SubCategoryId, psc.ProductId});
            
            modelBuilder.Entity<ProductSubCategory>()
                .HasOne(psc => psc.Product)
                .WithMany(p => p.SubCategories)
                .HasForeignKey(psc => psc.ProductId);

            modelBuilder.Entity<ProductSubCategory>()
                .HasOne(psc => psc.SubCategory)
                .WithMany(sc => sc.ProductSubCategories)
                .HasForeignKey(psc => psc.SubCategoryId);
}
```

I'm pretty sure i configure the relationship correctly.
Things i have tried:

1. Delete the migration folder and created a new one.
2. Update Ef Core nuget package to the latest version
3. Dropping the database and then create a new one.

PD: Please i need help, i'm out of time, if you want the source code of the entities project with it's respective Dbcontext, i can give it to you, but as i said, it has 19 entities classes.
This is the source code: https://github.com/ToastedGuy2/Food-Town-issue

**EDIT:** The real question was How to remove **`On Cascade On Delete`** in every foreign key? It doesn't matter if it is One to Many or Many to many relationship.

Comment: The error is telling you the problem: *"Introducing FOREIGN KEY constraint 'FK_ProductSubCategory_SubCategory_SubCategoryId' on table 'ProductSubCategory' may cause cycles or multiple cascade paths. Specify ON DELETE NO ACTION or ON UPDATE NO ACTION, or modify other FOREIGN KEY constraints."*

Comment: I don't understand it, can you please explain to me.

Comment: Which part? The error is quite clear, and explicit on the solution.

Comment: Not for me, I have forgotten lots of things about database, this is the first time, I'm facing it. Please can you provide me a solution to it?

Comment: Just search SO for "cycles or multiple cascade paths"

Comment: OK, let's start off, what doesn't make sense for the statement *"may cause cycles or multiple cascade paths"*? Then, after that, what part of *"Specify ON DELETE NO ACTION or ON UPDATE NO ACTION, or modify other FOREIGN KEY constraints."* don't you understand? Which specific parts are confusing you?

Comment: First one and second one, since i have never read anything related to it. I'm going to look up at the foreign keys. I was pretty sure, i configure it perfectly.

Comment: What is the difference between category and subcategory? Why do you have CategoryId and SubCategoryId in one class. Where is a Category class?

Comment: @Serge The difference is that the subcategory relies on category. So each category has many subcategories. For example: Meat Category, in will have beef, pork, fish,etc. So when i want to insert update a product, I have to select a category, so it can show the rest of the subcategories. I have to update the whole post, i made so much mistakes on this.

Answer (score 1):

> Introducing FOREIGN KEY constraint 'FK_ProductSubCategory_SubCategory_SubCategoryId' on table 'ProductSubCategory' may cause cycles or multiple cascade paths. Specify ON DELETE NO ACTION or ON UPDATE NO ACTION, or modify other FOREIGN KEY constraints.

The error is literally telling you the problem here. I am not sure what bit is unclear, as the OP states they understand none of it (which I must admit implies a language barrier and so I suggest changing the language of your `LOGIN` to get the error in a language you are more familiar with), however, I'm going to overly "dumb" this down:

> Introducing FOREIGN KEY constraint 'FK_ProductSubCategory_SubCategory_SubCategoryId'

This is talking about the `FOREIGN KEY` you are trying to create called `FK_ProductSubCategory_SubCategory_SubCategoryId`

> on table 'ProductSubCategory'

This is telling you that the aforementioned `FOREIGN KEY` is trying to be created on the table `ProductSubCategory`

> may cause cycles or multiple cascade paths.

This means that the aforementioned `FOREIGN KEY`, that is trying to be created on the aforementioned `TABLE`, will cause cycles or multiple cascade paths.

- A Cycle would mean that the `DELETE` will cause further deletes on the same table, trigging more deletes on the same table, trigging more deletes on the same table, ... trigging more deletes on the same table, ... (You get the idea)
- Multiple Cascade Paths means that there will be multiple other tables that will have rows deleted from, which is now allowed in SQL Server; especially if they converge on the same table later on.

> Specify ON DELETE NO ACTION or ON UPDATE NO ACTION

I don't really know how to clarify this further. Instead of `ON CASCADE` use `NO ACTION`. AKA, handle the cascading yourself.

> or modify other FOREIGN KEY constraints

Again, this is very much telling you what to do. Modify the other `CONSTRAINT`s on your table so that they won't cause a cycle or multiple paths; must likely by changing that key to `NO ACTION` and handing the cascading yourself.

Comment: Thank you for taking your time. How do i Specify **ON Delete NO Action**? Because I have noticed the whole project have them, and to be fair, it should not have them, so i basically have to tell ef core, to remove it, but how? Just to provide more context, in my project i don't delete records, i just disable them, with a **isItActive** boolean property.

Comment: Question: How does EF Core know if a foreign key is `ON DELETE CASCADE OR NO ACTION`. Because on many to many relationships, it added by default, i just followed the convention as other pages have said. When it comes to relationship one to many, i followed this convention #4 of this page: https://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/efcore/one-to-many-conventions-entity-framework-core.aspx . Basically it says :  Defining the relationship fully at both ends with the foreign key property in the dependent entity creates a one-to-many relationship.

Answer (score 1):

Try to change

```
 modelBuilder.Entity<ProductSubCategory>()
                .HasOne(psc => psc.Product)
                .WithMany(p => p.SubCategories)
                .HasForeignKey(psc => psc.ProductId);
```

To

```
 modelBuilder.Entity<ProductSubCategory>()
                .HasOne(psc => psc.Product)
                .WithMany(p => p.ProductSubCategories)
                .HasForeignKey(psc => psc.ProductId);
```

And I usually use  .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.ClientSetNull)

Comment: Serge, **SubCategories** property basically have a list of **ProductSubCategories**. So i don't understand where do you get **ProductSubCategories**. I guess i should rename the properties again, so it's more clear.

Comment: The next record in you code modelBuilder.Entity<ProductSubCategory>()
                .HasOne(psc => psc.SubCategory)
                .WithMany(sc => sc.ProductSubCategories)
                .HasForeignKey(psc => psc.SubCategoryId);

Comment: I mean the relationship is well configure, i just need to remove all `ON DELETE CASCADE` on my foreign keys.

Comment: Ok i'm going to try it.

Answer (score 1):

EF Core defaults to cascading deletes. This starts to cause problems once you have too many of them, and you don't want them all over the place anyway.

When defining your relationships, you should try to default to no cascade yourself, except in situations where you really do want a cascade.

```cs
entityBuilder
.HasMany(one => one.Many)
.WithOne(many => many.One)
.OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.NoAction);
```